# javascript create multi form add and remove

Tags: java, jquery, html, forms

I want to create a jsp page that dynamically remove and add form input like in the picture.

[image]

when i click add the form will add new form but if click minus sign the form will be removed.
[image]

I don't know how to do it, since i am poor on javascript and jquery. can you help me ?

Comment: Best bet would be to try and then post what you did...Help is easier from there

Comment: i don't well about javascript I just create raw html.

Comment: even if you posted that in a fiddle or codepen people would be more inclined to help